# HTML5 - SVG issue with rendering an image in IE 11

Tags: html, svg

I'm having a problem rendering an image in IE 11 using SVG. The problem does not exist in Chrome. I also have very little experience with SVG. And I only chose SVG in this case so that I could create an image map that works under iOS, which regular image maps do not.

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div>
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1200 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <image width="1200" height="800" xlink:href="/Images/PortalPageNonMobile.jpg"></image>

        <a xlink:href="http://www.wildlifenaturedestinations.com/Home/Index/?Redirect=false">
            <rect x="115" y="90" fill="#fff" opacity="0" width="310" height="95" />
        </a>

        <a xlink:href="http://www.wildlifenaturedestinations.com/Home/Index/?Redirect=false">
            <rect x="700" y="90" fill="#fff" opacity="0" width="330" height="95" />
        </a>
    </svg>
</div>
```

In Chrome, the image displays in the page, and consumes almost the entire page, as it should. However, in IE 11, the image is very small and is maybe 200 px x 200 px, instead of 1200 x 800. You can see a screen shot of it below. The image should consume most of the gray area, which is my browser background. Do I have incorrect syntax in my HTML that Chrome doesn't have an issue with, and IE does?

[image]

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271034/svg-with-viewbox-and-width-is-not-scaling-height-correctly-in-ie?

Comment: You forgot to set svg's height and width, IE doesn't like it...

Comment: @Kaiido - That seems to have fixed it. If you create this as an answer, I'll vote it up and accept it.

Comment: That would ask me to do some research about the specs and so on... Also, I guess there is already a dupe somewhere. I will first check for it, then if not found, search for the specs, and finally post an answer, but my guess is that the question should be closed instead of answered.

Comment: Can't find anything directly related... I will just add the comment as an answer then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only forgot to set svg's height and width, IE doesn't like it...

I didn't found the specs about it yet, but without a height nor width set, browser should consider it as `100%`, where IE seems to have some issues...

So either set absolute height and width attributes on the svg tag, or set it through css, either absolutely on the svg, or absolutely on its container (the `<div>` here), or relatively on every of its containers (`html,body,div{width: 100%; height:100%}` here).